# grunt - what is correct installation process?

Tags: gruntjs

I have my project files in the directory `/myproject`. I want `Grunt` to build files into `/myproject/www`. Here is what I've done:

1) Opened command line in `/myproject` and run the following command: `npm install -g grunt-cli` 
2) Opened command line in `/myproject` and run the following command: `npm install grunt --save-dev` 
. This command downloaded a bunch of files and created the folder `node_modules` inside `/myproject`. Here is the structure of the `node_modules`: `/myproject/node_modules/grunt/package.json`.

If I create file `Gruntfile.js` inside `/myproject/node_modules/grunt/` folder and run tasks from this folder, everything's OK. But I want to run tasks from the `/myproject` folder. So I moved Gruntfile.js and package.json files up from `/myproject/node_modules/grunt/` to `/myproject`. However, when I run `Grunt` now I get the following error: `>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?`
So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move files from `/myproject/node_modules/grunt`, those are for Grunt itself. You need to *create new files* in `/myproject`, a `package.json` file and a `Gruntfile.js` file. Then read the [Grunt documentation](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#package.json) to see how to configure Grunt. You'll need to add things like `grunt-contrib-concat` (or whatever other modules you want to use) to your `package.json`'s `"devDependencies": {}` section as well as inside your `Gruntfile.js`. The documentation linked to above will have examples of the structure for both files.